Spotify web api using spotipy
Hi there I am writing a flask app where a user can create a playlist in spotify by just passing a youtube playlist link the program works fine for myself but when others log in or gives access to the web api the playlist gets created in my account rather than on their account. This is my code below:
username = sp.me()['id']
#note : before creating playlist checking if the yt link is valid
sp.user_playlist_create(username,spotifyPlaylistName)playlistId = spotify.getPlaylistId(sp,username,playlistName=spotifyPlaylistName)
#get track ids of the spotify its actually songuri
trackIds = spotify.getTrackIds(sp,videoIds = videoId)

sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username,playlistId,trackIds)


def getPlaylistId(sp,username,playlistName):
    playlistId =''

    playlists = sp.user_playlists(username)

    #iterate to get that new created playlist
    for playlist in playlists['items']:
        if playlist['name'] == playlistName:
            playlistId = playlist['id']
    return playlistId


def getTrackIds(sp,videoIds):
    trackIds = []

    for title in videoIds:
        results = sp.search(q=f'{title}',type = 'track')
        if results['tracks']['total'] == 0: #if track isn't on spotify as queried, go to next track
            continue
        else:
            trackIds.append(results['tracks']['items'][0]['uri'])
    return trackIds

I would very much appreciate if someone can help me solve this problem and point out the issue.
I tried searching on the internet to solve this but could not find anywhere, all github repo or websites were where the program ran only for the creator.

This issue is most likely occurring because the application is configured to use a single set of Spotify credentials—specifically, yours. As a result, all interactions with the Spotify API, including calls to sp.me()['id'], are using your account details. To ensure that users can create playlists in their own Spotify accounts, you will need to implement user-specific authentication. This involves setting up a login flow that allows users to authenticate with Spotify directly,
